# clipping the reward for adam optimizer in keras

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, keras, optimization, gradient-descent

I would like to clip the reward in keras. I saw it is possible to clip the norm and clip the value is sgd as follows:

```
sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, clipnorm=1.)
sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, clipvalue=0.5)
```

What are clipping the norm and clipping the value?

Also, How it is possible to implement the clipping the reward for **Adam**? Would you please let me know how I can do this?

Comment: Duplicate here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36498127/how-to-apply-gradient-clipping-in-tensorflow

Comment: ^ That is a different question, not a duplicate imo

Answer (score 5):

Gradient clipping takes two main forms in Keras: gradient norm scaling (`clipnorm`) and gradient value clipping (`clipvalue`).

### 1. Gradient Norm Scaling

> Gradient norm scaling involves changing the derivatives of the loss function to have a given vector norm when the L2 vector norm (sum of the squared values) of the gradient vector exceeds a threshold value.
>   For example, we could specify a norm of 1.0, meaning that if the vector norm for a gradient exceeds 1.0, then the values in the vector will be rescaled so that the norm of the vector equals 1.0.

### 2. Gradient Value Clipping

> Gradient value clipping involves clipping the derivatives of the loss function to have a given value if a gradient value is less than a negative threshold or more than the positive threshold. For example, we could specify a norm of 0.5, meaning that if a gradient value was less than -0.5, it is set to -0.5 and if it is more than 0.5, then it will be set to 0.5.

### 3. Keras Syntax

The gradient clipping syntax for Adaptive Moment Estimation (Adam) is very simple and follows the same syntax as for Stochastic Gradient Descent (SGD) shown above:

```
opt_adam = optimizers.adam(clipnorm=1.)
opt_adam = optimizers.adam(clipvalue=0.5)
```